# php failed to open stream

Tags: php, stream

I have an error, I think it has to do with the directory of the public_html file but I'm not sure.

The Error:

```
Warning: require(__DIR__/protected/bootstrap/autoload.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home4/nameguy/public_html/index.php on line 21

Warning: require(__DIR__/protected/bootstrap/autoload.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home4/nameguy/public_html/index.php on line 21

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '__DIR__/protected/bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home4/nameguy/public_html/index.php on line 21
```

Index.php code:

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/protected/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/protected/bootstrap/start.php';

$app->run();

$app->shutdown();
```

Answer (score 2):

`__DIR__` is only defined since PHP 5.3 so maybe you have an older version. You can use `__FILE__` instead:

```
<?php
require dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/bootstrap/start.php';
```

Comment: I now get this error: http://pastebin.com/JT0xhR7s - Autoload code: http://pastebin.com/pr5zRAHM | I don't mean to ask everything :3 I'm just lost when it comes to PHP and most questions I find already answered are too advanced for my current level of PHP

Comment: please provide some explanation for your code in order users to understand what is being done now?

Comment: @zkanoca, I have updated my answer, most likely `__DIR__` is not defined for him.

Comment: @user3555497, so the two require statements work now. The error you are having is something different, please post the source code so that we can check what the issue might be.

Comment: I still get the same error as before with your updated answer on line 46 of autoload.php Heres auto loads source code: http://pastebin.com/pr5zRAHM and here's paths.php source code: http://pastebin.com/v1m90n78

Comment: @user3555497, you are using an old version of PHP that doesn't support namespaces. You need to either upgrade PHP or use a framework other than Laravel. Kohana or Zend 1.x for example should work.